Make Azure Monitor alert changes to an app registration's API permissions
Is there a way I can make Azure Monitor alert an administrator when an application registration's API permission is edited?


You can enable Diagnostic settings in Log analytics workspace to send all Azure AD logs to LAW and fetch only Category == "ApplicationManagement and OperationName == "Updateapplication" using KQL query.

I found out that we already had some Golang scripts that got the information that I was looking for and put it inside a .csv file. So I just ended up using that.


Is there a way I can make Azure Monitor alert an administrator when an application registration's API permission is edited?


Create a Log analytics for exporting logs from Azure AD
Create a Diagnostic setting by navigating Azure Entra ID >  Diagnostic settings > Add diagnostic setting



Once the Diagnostic settings are added, wait for some time for the logs to sync to the Log Analytics Workspace , and then execute the KQL query below to fetch logs if an application's API permissions have been modified.

AuditLogs
| where Category == "ApplicationManagement"
| where OperationName in ("Consent to application", "Add app role assignment to service principal", "Remove app role assignment from service principal")

KQL Query Result:

You can follow the Stack link answered by me to create an action group for triggering an email.

Once you create an alert, you will receive a email notification to your email id if an Azure AD application's API permission is edited.

I think you can do this either by checking AD audit logs (but that may be  more tedious and possibly doesn't catch every condition you're looking for):
https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Threat-Research-Matrix/PrivilegeEscalation/AZT405/AZT405-3/#azure-monitor-alert
Or you could enable "Activity Logging", and for instance create a Log Analytics Workspace in Azure Monitor and build KQL queries for your use case.
There's all sort of clever stuff you can do with those activity logs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log?tabs=powershell
I hope this helps, I've never implemented this myself though ..
